# PHP Convert Array Keys

Tags: php, arrays

Had a hard time wording this in google so I figure ill ask here.

I have an array like such:

```
Array ( [a] => 'a' [b] => 'b' [c] => 'c' )
```

Is there an easy way to convert the keys to numerical values like such? Is there a built in function, or will I have to make one?

```
Array ( [0] => 'a' [1] => 'b' [2] => 'c' )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You want the [array_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function.

Comment: This accepted answer is too short, and I don't know whether the external link will still exist in the future.

Answer (score 19):

Use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/function.array-values), as in the manual example:

```
<?php
$array = array("size" => "XL", "color" => "gold");
print_r(array_values($array));
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => XL
    [1] => gold
)
```

Comment: This will work with one-directional arrays, but not multi-dimensional. For that, you'll need a recursive function.

Comment: The question was about a one dimensional array.

Comment: It sure was. However those looking for a similar solution for a multidimensional array will appreciate knowing up front that this answer won't help them. Don't ever be afraid to explain where ( and where not ) a solution may apply.

Answer (score 5):

Try array_values

```
$arrayWithNumericKeys = array_values($arrayWithRegularKeys);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$my_array = array( [a] => 'a' [b] => 'b' [c] => 'c' )
$my_new_array = array_values($my_array);
```