# Change value in first of two arrays (multidimensional) PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to change the number in the first array in a multidimensional array. I have a code that outputs the value to an array and there is no chance for it to start counting from one - in my code. So my idea is to change the value starting from one - after it has been declared. My array look like this:

```
Array
(
    [53] => Array
        (
            [name] => Volkswagen
            [regularePrice] => 2139.00
        )

    [54] => Array
        (
            [name] => BMW
            [regularePrice] => 2219.00
        )

    [55] => Array
        (
            [name] => Chrysler
            [regularePrice] => 2399.00
        )
)
```

I want - through a while or for - go through the array and change the values 53 to 1, 54 to 2, 55 to 3 and so on depending on how long the array is.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Convert Array Keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446942/php-convert-array-keys)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

```
array_values($arr);
```

Comment: Ouww, that was piece of a cake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

```
$array = array_values($array);
```