# How to convert Multi-Dimensional Associative array in to Numeric Array in php, without looping?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, split

I created a working function for splitting following associative array into two numeric array. I wonder if there is a better method , avoid looping.

I have an array as follows.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [CreatedAt] => 16/02/2014
            [Occurrence] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [CreatedAt] => 17/02/2014
            [Occurrence] => 8
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [CreatedAt] => 18/02/2014
            [Occurrence] => 4
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [CreatedAt] => 20/02/2014
            [Occurrence] => 11
        )

)
```

Need to convert it into two numerical array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 16/02/2014
    [1] => 17/02/2014
    [2] => 18/02/2014
    [3] => 20/02/2014
)

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 11
)
```

I used a `foreach` loop

```
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();
foreach ($mainArray as $key => $value) {
    $array1[] = $value->CreatedAt;
    $array2[] = $value->Occurrence;
}
print_r($array1);
print_r($array2);
```

But if I have 1000 rows in mainArray, it will affect the performance. If you have a better solution, let us all know that.

Comment: you can use `array_values` for it. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446942/php-convert-array-keys

Comment: In addition to @SatishSharma answer you will need array_keys too I think. Not sure though how fast (faster) this would be than your solution.

Comment: Is it an associative array or an object? Based on what you posted it appears to be the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$objName = (object) array('aFlat' => array());

    array_walk_recursive($array, create_function('&$v, $k, &$t', '$t->aFlat[] = $v;'), $objName);

    var_dump($objName->aFlat);
```

**REFER:** [How to "flatten" a multi-dimensional array to simple one in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/array_column

may be this could solve your problem!!

Comment: It's a good solution. But array_column is available in php 5.5 and above. Most of the servers are running in php 5.3 and 5.4.